add object from array into a Map() Javascript/Node
Is there any way to add an array of objects into a Map() ?
I want to add a username from the array each time i call the function add().
Quick example:
let localHashMap = new Map();
let arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']; // etc

function add(arrayNumber) {
    addToMap(arr[arrayNumber]);
}

function addToMap(username) {
    localHashMap.set('users', { 'user': username }); // <-- add? put? set?

    let obj;
    if (localHashMap.has('users')) {
        obj = localHashMap.get('users');
    }
    //Then i will use a loop to get the results 
    
    console.log(obj);

    //Output example
    //{ user: fff }
    //{ user: ddd }
    //{ user: aaa }
    //etc
}

Thanks in advance!
I try to figure it out but no luck at all..

You would store an array as the value, and then when you want to add a user, you'd take the array out of the Map, and push to it like you normally would.

Is localMap supposed to be localHashMap?

@Carcigenicate i cannot do this because the username's are random not const and stored into a map from random user's properties so each time i want to change the map from the certain user i would call the add and i would take the username from somewhere else, this is an example. Thank you for the answer.

@Barmar migration from Java.

I'm not sure what that has to do with the fact that you refer to it with two different names in your code. Are those supposed to be the same variable or not?

@Barman ohh i see it i will edit it asap Thank you!

Fetch the array from the Map; if it doesn't exist, initialize it to an empty array. Then push the new item onto the array.


let localHashMap = new Map();
let arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']; // etc

function add(arrayNumber) {
  addToMap(arr[arrayNumber]);
}

function addToMap(username) {
  let users;
  if (localHashMap.has('users')) {
    users = localHashMap.get('users');
  } else {
    users = [];
    localHashMap.set('users', users);
  }
  users.push({user: username});

  console.log(users);
}

add(3);
add(5);
add(2);




Barmar thank you very much for your answer i will try it tomorrow morning!

I figure it out thanks to @Barman with a little bit of modification because i want them inside the Map() as Object.
if (localHasMap.has('users')) {
   users = localHasMap.get('users');
   } else {
   users = new Map();
   users.set('user', username);
   }
localHasMap.set('users', Object.fromEntries(users));

Thank you all.
